# how to refresh bindings in textBox?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I refresh bindings I mean run Property Get of the field which is Bound to the text manually :/ I cant find solution. My textBox is bound to bindingSource. I want to refresh this bindingSource manually

Comment: @alpha-mouse: bindingSource is a class in System.Windows.Forms, in WPF wo use DataContext property to the data sources.

Answer (score 2):

```
bindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();
```

Causes a control bound to the BindingSource to reread the currently selected item and refresh its displayed value.

---

```
bindingSource.ResetBindings();
```

Causes a control bound to the BindingSource to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values.